# Do I need to install anything before playing Games in WINE

Tags: drivers, wine, games

Do I need to install 3D drivers such as DirectX before playing games in WINE?

I have played Counter Strike using Wine , But there was errors..

What Should I do??

Comment: Again, what is the *exact* error? If we can't get it, this question may be closed as NARQ as it lacks enough information to be answered.

Comment: For the possible close voters: The question isn't that unclear (IMO). He was asking whether he needs installing something like DirectX (as required in Windows) before playing games on WINE.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ The error must be this: The counterstrike doesn't working on wine.

Comment: @lambda23 No. I need a specific error. Is it a problem in loading a library(what library?), or something like OPenGL, or something else altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Normally you don't need to install DirectX or anything to run games in WINE which are well supported. The necessary libraries ( from DirectX ) are automatically installed with WINE.

[This page from WINE website](http://appdb.winehq.org/) lists the names of applications and games which is supported very well under WINE.

But, sometimes you may need to override some specific libraries from newer version of DirectX in WINE for better performance.

We could give you more specific answer if you had posted the errors about the Counter Strike game.